# Checking uniform convergence of $x^n(1-x)$ and $x^n(1-x^n)$ on $[0,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

> Consider $f_n(x)=x^n(1-x)$ and $g_n(x)=x^n(1-x^n)$ for $x$ in $[0,1]$. Discuss if they are uniformly convergent.

*My answer:* It can be shown that the pointwise limit of both is zero function on $[0,1]$. Thus, for uniform convergence on $[0,1]$, we check if 
$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]} |f_n(x)| \rightarrow 0 \mbox{ and } \sup_{x\in [0,1]}|g_n(x)|\rightarrow 0 \mbox{ as } n\rightarrow \infty.$$
Now $f_n$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ with $|f_n(x)|\le 1$.

By continuity the supremum of $|f_n(x)|$ is attained at some $c\in (0,1)$ (since $|f_n(0)|=|f_n(1)|=0$).

Then we necessarily have $f'(c)=0$.  We can see that $c=n/(n+1)$  and so 
$$\sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f_n(x)|=|f_n(c)|=(\frac{n}{n+1})^n.\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{n+1} \rightarrow 0 \mbox{ as } n\rightarrow \infty$$
So convergence is uniform.

Similar way, for $g_n$, if $c$ is point of maximum for $|g_n(x)|$ then $c=(\frac{1}{2})^{1/n}$ and $|g_n(c)|=\frac{1}{4}$, which does not tend to $0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$; so convergence is not uniform.

**Q.1** Is the solution correct?

**Q.2** What are other alternative ways for solving them?

Comment: $\sum_{x\in [0,1]} |f_n(x)|$ ? Do you mean $\sup_{x\in [0,1]} |f_n(x)|$ ?

Comment: Note that the problem you are facing is adressed by Dini's theorem. And furthermore that theorem does not require derivability but some knowledge the real line(s topology. Anyway, your solution seems correct to me except for the typo @MartinR is talking about.

Comment: @Martin: Yes; I was typing \sup but it typed \sum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer is correct (except that you wrote $sum$ for supremum) . A perhaps simpler way is to note that $f_n(x) \leq 1-x <\delta$ whenever $x> 1-\delta$ and $f_n(x) \leq x^{n} \leq (1-\delta)^{n}$ for $0 \leq x \leq \delta$. Now use the fact that $(1-\delta)^{n} \to 0$ to complete the proof.

To show that $g_n$ does not tend to $0$ uniformly use the fact that $g_n(1-\frac 1 n) \to \frac 1 e (1-\frac 1 e )$